# How to vertically align headers/footers in fancyhdr package?

Tags: vertical-alignment, header-footer

I'm using `fancyhdr`package for headings and footers. I have defined left-header as a big image, and I want to vertically align (to the top or to the center, the default is to the bottom) the text from the right-header. How can I do that?

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{\includegraphics[height=21mm]{some_fancy_logo.pdf}}
\chead{}
\rhead{I want to vertically align THIS text}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=21mm]{some_fancy_logo.pdf}}}

\chead{}

\rhead{I want to vertically align THIS text}

\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

And don't ignore the warning of `fancyhdr`:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 59.75078pt.
```

Use  `\headheight=22mm` or something like this.

Comment: Nice idea... but unfortunately it doesn't work correctly. As I understand, I should use -1 for top-aligned, and -0.5 for center-aligned. Well, the raisebox seems to be off by 1em. (and sorry for the LONG delay before testing this)

Comment: Well it does work for me, I tested it. So something is different on your side: Either you changed the code or the graphic (which I don't have) inserts some border. Also I don't know what you mean by "off by 1em". "Off" relative to what?

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution. It's a very ugly hack, but it works in my case (because I know in advance the height of the header).

```
\rhead{\parbox[b][21mm][t]{0.5\textwidth}{\raggedleft I want to vertically align THIS text}}
```

I'm accepting better solutions. :)

Comment: though this doesn't work if you have the LE,RO type headers and parbox internally aligns text.. there might be a way to do an if then from external header position things - raisebox does obey LE,RO but you have to do things line by line

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that in `fancyhdr` there is no easy way to communicate the width of a box in the left header to the right header.  You could allocate a dimen register, place the width of the box in the left header into it, and use it in the right header, but I think much easier solution is to just place everything into the same header:

```
\lhead{\hbox to \hsize{%
       \hbox{\vtop{\vskip 0pt \hbox{\includegraphics[height=21mm]{some-fancy-logo.pdf}}}}%
       \hfill\hbox{\vtop{\vskip 0pt \hbox{I want to vertically align THIS text}}}}}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
```

You probably don't even need `fancyhdr`.

Comment: Geez... What does all of that mean? Care to add a small description of what's going on there, in plain English?

Comment: Rather that trying to explain it clumsily myself, I will point you yo an excellent explanation by Victor Eijkhout in his TeX by Topics, at http://eijkhout.net/texbytopic/texbytopic.html.  You want to look at the chapter on Boxes.