# Align text and logo in footer

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, header-footer

I can't seem to be able to align our logo and page number in the footer. I have the code below:

```
\pagestyle{fancy} % enable fancy page style
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhf{} % clear header and footer
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark} % leftmark shows the chapter, rightmark shows the section.
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{ % right
   \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{general_images/logo.png}
}
```

How can I align the page number and the logo? Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a *full* [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: You want them aligned how? We can't see your logo image. How big is the logo? Should the bottom of the logo align with the baseline of the text? Should the top of the logo align with the baseline plus the ex height? Explain what you want. "align" is pretty vague...

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, there's another question asking about the same thing: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2440/how-to-vertically-align-headers-footers-in-fancyhdr-package. Please let us know if that solves your problem. If so, we'll probably close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @doncherry: Now I see your link--yes, very similar question. If the answer here (with calculation for different alignment) would be a bit more useful, we might mark the other existing question as duplicate instead.

Answer (score 3):

With `\includegraphics`, the base line for alignment is at the bottom. You could use `\raisebox` to raise or to lower the image. The `calc` package can help in calculating if required. For example for top alignment

```
\usepackage{calc}
\fancyfoot[R]{
  \raisebox{1.2ex-\height}{\includegraphics{logo.png}}}
```

or with more calculation

```
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\myheight}
\fancyfoot[R]{
  \settoheight{\myheight}{\thepage}
  \raisebox{\myheight-\height}{\includegraphics{logo.png}}}
```

or for middle alignment instead

```
\raisebox{.5\myheight-.5\height}{\includegraphics{logo.png}}
```